# How can I join multiple strings with logical operators to create a search term with for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, search, concatenation, logical-operators

I want to create a search term, depending on the input given. For example, when the user provides the phone number "69420" and name "Karen", the following code:

```
getbools = [f"{phone}" != "", f"{id}" != "", f"{name.replace(' ', ':')}" != "", f"{email}" != ""] #  [1, 0, 1, 0]
searches = [f"{phone}", f"{id}", f"{name.replace(' ', ':')}", f"{email}"]
search = operator.and_.join(search for i in searches if getbools[i])
print(search)
```

should yield a the following search term

> search = "69420" and "Karen"

However, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'join'

I want to use this search term afterwards in a for loop searching the **search** in the lines of a .txt file and further process them.
Sadly, I could not come up with a solution yet and probably, I'm overcomplicating this and there's a simpler way. Hope you can help me find a better solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To make sure I understand, do you want to check if a given line in the txt file contains all the search terms? And perhaps print the lines that do?

Comment: Yes, I want to check if a given line contains the terms provided and print them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Open the txt files using the context manager `with` statement
with open("txtfile.txt") as f:
    txtfile = f.readlines()

# Get the search terms
searches = [f"{phone}", f"{id}", f"{name.replace(' ', ':')}", f"{email}"]
# Removes falsy values (like you did with `!= ""`)
searches = [element for element in searches if element]

# Loop thru the lines and check if all search terms occur. 
# If they do, print the line
for line in txtfile:
    if all(search_term in line for search_term in searches):
        print(line.strip())
```

As a side note, its better practise to call your `id` variable `id_` or something, so it doesn't overwrite the built-in `id` function.